# В чем причина ошибки: "не найден псевдоним Convert"?

Tags: c#, .net

Что делать? Может какой-нибудь класс надо добавить?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text += "1";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text += "9";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox1.Text->Text); 
            int b = Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox2.Text->Text);
            textBox3.Text = a+b;
        }
    }
}
```

**Добавлено.**

После смены кода на
`(textBox3.Text = Convert::ToInt32(textBox1.Text)) + (Convert::ToInt32(textBox2.Text));`
ошибок стало 2. Только одна ошибка вот эта:

> Квалификатор псевдонима пространства имен "::" всегда разрешается в тип или пространство имен, что в данном случае недопустимо. Рассмотрите возможность использования ".".

На Visual Studio 2010 я выбрал самый первый пункт - Приложение Windows Forms = Visual C#.

Comment: Код в студию

Comment: Часть 1

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text += "1";
        }

Comment: @navi1893 Используйте правку вопроса для добавления кода.

Comment: не по теме:

``textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text += "1";`` эквивалентно ``textBox1.Text += "1";``

по теме:

класс Convert входит в пространсто System, поэтому в using`е ничего дописывать не надо и __по идее__ ``Convert::ToInt32(textBox2.Text);`` должен исправно работать

Answer (score 2):

Напишите просто

```
textBox3.Text=(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)+Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
```

И исправьте метку на C#.

Comment: Ошибка:

Неявное преобразование типа "int" в "string" невозможно

Comment: Точно, забыл, обновил ответ!

Comment: Наконец-то! Спасибо тебе за все, реально ты мне очень очень помог!

P.S можно я тебя добавлю в меил ру?

Comment: Примите ответ, этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо "::" из C++ в C# нужно использовать ".". Двойное двоеточие в C# означает другое. Оно должно применяться для псевдонимов пространств имён. Например, есть вложенное пространство имён `HashCode.GLMonster.Application`. Если его хотим использовать в корневом пространстве имён, то придётся длинно писать `HashCode.GLMonster.Application.Variable`. Можно сделать так: `using App=HashCode.GLMonster.Application`, тогда к этому пространству можно будет обращаться кратко `App::Variable`.

Кстати, строку в текст ещё можно преобразовывать через `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Подключите класс [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert.aspx#Y0).

Comment: А куда его дописать? Вот наверху в комменте я написал код, можешь показать после чего написать его?

Comment: C++ давно не изучал, может ошибаюсь, но попробуй в самом начале дописать using System.Object.Convert или using.System.Convert

Comment: при using.System.Convert выдает ошибку:


Директива using namespace может применяться только к пространствам имен; "System.Convert" является типом, а не пространством имен

Answer (score 0):

Класс Convert объявлен в пространстве имен System. Оно уже подключено. Возможно аргумент вызова неопределен, попробуйте вместо

```
int a = Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox1.Text->Text); 
int b = Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox2.Text->Text);
```

сделать

```
int a = Convert::ToInt32("1"); 
int b = Convert::ToInt32("2");
```

Если ошибка исчезнет, что-то не то `this->textBox1.Text->Text` и `this->textBox2.Text->Text`.

Comment: а щас вот эта ошибка в 2х местах

Квалификатор псевдонима пространства имен "::" всегда разрешается в тип или пространство имен, что в данном случае недопустимо. Рассмотрите возможность использования ".". 

и вот эта:

Директива using namespace может применяться только к пространствам имен; "System.Convert" является типом, а не пространством имен